# Is there documentation available to upgrade Artifactory OSS version to latest 7.15.3?

Tags: artifactory

We want to upgrade Artifactory OSS version from 5.4.4 to latest 7.15.3.  Is there documentation for how to proceed? And can upgrade be done directly between these version, or is intermediate upgrade necesssary first?

Answer (score 2):

The OSS version behaves pretty much the same as the Pro when it comes to upgrading. You should follow the [official documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingfromVersionBelow6.10). In general, you will want to upgrade to 6.10.0 and then you can upgrade to the latest 7.x.

The upgrade to 6.x should not result in any major changes but the final upgrade to 7.x does have [big changes you should review](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/What%27s+New%3A+Self-Hosted). The most obvious is that the application now needs two ports to run (8081 and 8082). If you have a reverse proxy, that will need to be updated when you jump to 7.x to accommodate this change, as well as potentially having to modify firewall rules.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Question: To upgrade the OSS version on our Linux platform, I see a gz file to upgrade from 6.10.x to 7.x, but I only see rpm to upgrade from 5.4.4 to 6.10.x.  Is that correct?

Comment: What you want is the [archive installer instructions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-LinuxArchiveUpgrade).  In terms of downloads, grab the [Linux archive from the releases Artifactory](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/org/artifactory/oss/jfrog-artifactory-oss/).

Comment: The linux archive only goes back to 6.23.13. If I need 6.10, looks like (Linux platform), looks like only thing available is rpm file?

Comment: I see. You want the 6.10.0 OSS version. You can find all versions in the [bintray-artifactory directory](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/). You will want [jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.10.0.zip](https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/bintray-artifactory/jfrog-artifactory-oss-6.10.0.zip)

Comment: If we don't have a separate server to use as a test bed for new upgrade version of Artifactory, is it possible (or recommended) to be able to stand up 2 different versions on same server?

Comment: And a more general question.  If we are using OSS version, is it possible to get support for upgrade questions?

Comment: Only the paid versions come with support.  If you are worried about the upgrade, just make a backup. If you need to keep it up and running, I suggest an export/import into the new versions.

Comment: @Arturo Aparicio do you have an updated link for where to find modern oss artifactory links.